# C++/CLR managed unit test has linker errors

Tags: c++, clr, linker-errors

When including any managed class to my managed unit test the compile spits out these errors:

```
1>UnitTest.obj : error LNK2020: unresolved token (0A000360) "extern "C" int __cdecl _CrtDbgReportW(int,wchar_t const *,int,wchar_t const *,wchar_t const *,...)" (?_CrtDbgReportW@@$$J0YAHHPB_WH00ZZ)
1>UnitTest.obj : error LNK2020: unresolved token (0A000361) "extern "C" int __cdecl _CrtDbgReportW(int,wchar_t const *,int,wchar_t const *,wchar_t const *,...)" (?_CrtDbgReportW@@$$J0YAHHPB_WH00ZZ)
1>UnitTest.obj : error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A0003E6) "extern "C" void __cdecl _invalid_parameter(wchar_t const *,wchar_t const *,wchar_t const *,unsigned int,unsigned int)" (?_invalid_parameter@@$$J0YAXPB_W00II@Z) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall std::_Iterator_base12::_Orphan_me(void)" (?_Orphan_me@_Iterator_base12@std@@$$FQAEXXZ)
1>UnitTest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "extern "C" void __cdecl _invalid_parameter(wchar_t const *,wchar_t const *,wchar_t const *,unsigned int,unsigned int)" (?_invalid_parameter@@$$J0YAXPB_W00II@Z) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall std::_Iterator_base12::_Orphan_me(void)" (?_Orphan_me@_Iterator_base12@std@@$$FQAEXXZ)
1>UnitTest.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "extern "C" int __cdecl _CrtDbgReportW(int,wchar_t const *,int,wchar_t const *,wchar_t const *,...)" (?_CrtDbgReportW@@$$J0YAHHPB_WH00ZZ)
```

I am using a clr project as well as including a managed class. Removing the include allows the test to compile.

Comment: I had a similar problem when I added an unmanaged std::list<int> to my test project. The fix below worked. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/51834198/2472504

Answer (score 6):

To solve this issue you must remove

> "_DEBUG"

from the test project in

> [TestProject] -> Properties -> C/C++ --> Preprocessor --> Preprocessor
>   Definitions

Alternitively you can change

> "_DEBUG" to "NDEBUG"

Comment: A project in debug mode which doesn't define `_DEBUG` - this sounds strange to me. (I must admit that I never used these MS clr things.) I just created a new CLR project in VS2013. In debug mode, `_DEBUG` is defined on command line by default.