# Issues with a C++ Test Project in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, unit-testing, visual-studio-2010, std

I have been having problems making a C++ Test Project work in Visual Studio 2010. I am looking for what is wrong/what to do about it.

This kind of test project has to be compiled as managed code. No problem. C++ can be built that way. I did it this trivial example std::list example. I created a C++ CLR project. I pasted this code in and compiled. I can step through the code as it runs. It works.

```
 #include "stdafx.h"
 #include <list>

using namespace System;

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    std::list<int> list;
    list.push_back(1);

    int& pt = list.front();
    list.pop_front();

    return 0;
}
```

I started over with a new C++ Test project. Because this is C++ code, I went to the project's properties > Configuration Properties > C/C++ > General > Common Language RunTime Support, and changed /clr:safe to /clr.

I created a basic test named ListTests and pasted the same code in a test named ListTest(). I get this when I build.

```
1>ListTests.obj : error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A0000E9) "extern "C" int __cdecl _CrtDbgReportW(int,wchar_t const *,int,wchar_t const *,wchar_t const *,...)" (?_CrtDbgReportW@@$$J0YAHHPB_WH00ZZ) referenced in function "public: class std::_List_const_iterator<class std::_List_val<int,class std::allocator<int> > > & __thiscall std::_List_const_iterator<class std::_List_val<int,class std::allocator<int> > >::operator++(void)" (??E?$_List_const_iterator@V?$_List_val@HV?$allocator@H@std@@@std@@@std@@$$FQAEAAV01@XZ)
1>ListTests.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "extern "C" int __cdecl _CrtDbgReportW(int,wchar_t const *,int,wchar_t const *,wchar_t const *,...)" (?_CrtDbgReportW@@$$J0YAHHPB_WH00ZZ) referenced in function "public: class std::_List_const_iterator<class std::_List_val<int,class std::allocator<int> > > & __thiscall std::_List_const_iterator<class std::_List_val<int,class std::allocator<int> > >::operator++(void)" (??E?$_List_const_iterator@V?$_List_val@HV?$allocator@H@std@@@std@@@std@@$$FQAEAAV01@XZ)
```

The problem appears whenever iterators are used. For example, if I comment out the last two lines - the ones that use front() and pop_front(), all is well. These methods use iterators internally.

If I change to boost, everything is fine. E.G. I can use boost::intrusive::list in a more complex function. It works fine.

Thoughts?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49289854/c-clr-managed-unit-test-has-linker-errors ?

Comment: `Crt`... sounds like the runtime library is missing (not found, not mentioned). Did you try to setup a new project from template for the same sources?

Comment: @T2PS Thanks for the link - just had a look at it. I'm in doubt if this is really a help for OP. I guess it's worth to puzzle this question out.

Comment: @T2PS,@Scheff - Thanks. It is a duplicate. I changed _DEBUG to NDEBUG, and it works.